# Subsetting a list of xts based on list of row indexes

Tags: r, xts

I am struggling with a problem on how to subset xts objects stored within a list. **The subsetting shall happen based on row indexes**. The background is that I want to split the objects randomly 80/20 into training and test set. 
Here is an example:

```
library(xts)

# Create a sample list with dummy data
series <- list(
  A=xts(rnorm(n=200), as.Date("2015-01-01")+1:200),
  B=xts(rnorm(n=50), as.Date("2015-04-01")+1:50)
)
```

Note: the length of these xts objects differ on purpose.

The `trainIndex` is a list that contains row numbers that split each xts object on 80/20 basis as per the `createDataPartition`function from the `caret` package:

```
# create am index of row numbers for splitting the dataset
library(caret)
trainIndex <- lapply(series, function(x) {createDataPartition(x, p=0.8)})
```

And this is what I was expecting to work:

```
series.test <- lapply(series, function(x) x[trainIndex,])
```

which it didn't.

This works for a 'static' vector (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247625/using-lapply-to-subset-rows-from-data-frames-incorrect-number-of-dimensions-e)):

```
trainIndex.simple <- seq(1,50,by=3)
lapply(series, function(x) x[trainIndex.simple,])
```

And this works on one list element

```
series$A[trainIndex$A[[1]],]
```

But how to apply the list of row indices on a list of xts objects?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683531/subset-list-of-xts-objects) might be helpful somehow, but I couldn't translate it to my problem...

Any hint is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a function that loops over both lists at the same time. For example: `mapply`, or `Map` (which calls `mapply`):

```
set.seed(21)
trainIndex <- lapply(series, function(x)
  sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), nrow(x), TRUE, c(0.8, 0.2)))
series.test <- mapply(function(x, i) x[i,], x=series, i=trainIndex)
series.test <- Map(function(x, i) x[i,], x=series, i=trainIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks @'Joshua Ulrich', this did solve my problem. I realize there is a difference what type the subsetting element is: `createDataPartition` creates a numeric vector with row indices, while your solution creates a logical vector (TRUE/FALSE) - that seems to be important.

Comment: @Stephan: whether `trainIndex` is numeric or logical should not matter. You can subset xts objects by either. You could transform my `trainIndex` via `lapply(trainIndex, which)` and you will obtain the same result when you use it to create `series.test`.